# Add eighth and ninth lines to all *.txt files

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

i have more than 100 txt files in C:\myfolder*.txt
when i run this script from "C:\myfolder" i can add eighth and ninth lines to somename.txt

```
@echo off
powershell "$f=(Get-Content somename.txt);$f[8]='heretext1';$f | set-content somename.txt"
powershell "$f=(Get-Content somename.txt);$f[9]='heretext2';$f | set-content somename.txt"
```

but how can i add eighth and ninth lines to all *.txt files located in path C:\myfolder*.txt
Can someone explain me how to do it please...

---

Sorry for my English and Sorry if i didn't explaned my problem. i will try now:

I uses "*.uci" files, instead of *.txt files. i wrote txt because uci extensions are unknown for most of the people. These *.uci files are settings for chess engines with uci protocol.
So when you use chessbase program you have a lot of chess engines and each engine creates their "enginename.uci" file.
If you want to change the numbers of core used on your PC from 1 to 16 you need to do it manually by adding following information in *.uci file like this:

```
[OPTIONS] 
Threads=1
```

That's why is better to make small batch or ps1 to change settings to all engines by adding these two lines with one click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this PowerShell script would suit your task:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\myfolder' -Filter '*.txt' | ForEach-Object {
$LineIndex = 0
$FileContent = Switch -File $_.FullName {Default {
$LineIndex++
If ($LineIndex -Eq 8) {@'
heretext1
heretext2
'@}
$_}}
Set-Content -Path $_.FullName -Value $FileContent}
```

Comment: It's doesn't work, sorry

Comment: Please expand on that comment, @Antivoyager. How are you running it, and what exactly happens. Have you tried just pasting the raw code above directly in a PowerShell Prompt window, and pressing the `[ENTER]` key?

Comment: 1) I saved your code to run.ps1 file and after i ran it -> nothing happened

Comment: @Antivoyager, I have corrected my code and removed all indentation because the site formatting was somehow invalidating it. Please try it again.

Comment: Thank you! Now it works fine!!! But always one question, why it didn't work if my text files are blank?

Comment: If you have blank text files then clearly it is not possible to insert  two lines lines after line 7. The task would be to write to a file seven empty lines and your two requested ones, and that was certainly not your question.

Comment: Thank you Compo and mclement0 for the help I received from you.
Excuse me if I didn't understand some of the questions and answers,
I'm really grateful to you!
Problem solved!

Answer (score 2):

Note:

- Your code isn't *adding* lines, it is *modifying existing* lines. The solution below does the same.
- Indices `[8]` and `[9]` access the *9th and 10th* lines, not the *8th and 9th*, given that array indexing is `0`-based.

---

You need to call [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) with your file-name pattern, `C:\myfolder\*.txt`, and process each matching file via [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object):

```bash
@echo off

powershell "Get-ChildItem C:\myfolder\*.txt | ForEach-Object { $f=$_ | Get-Content -ReadCount 0; $f[8]='heretext1'; $f[9]='heretext2'; Set-Content $_.FullName $f }"
```

Due to calling from a batch file (`cmd.exe`), the PowerShell command is specified on a single line; here's the readable version:

```bash
Get-ChildItem C:\myfolder\*.txt |             # get all matching files
  ForEach-Object {                            # process each
    $f = $_ | Get-Content -ReadCount 0        # read all lines
    $f[8] = 'heretext1'; $f[9] = 'heretext2'  # update the 9th and 10th line
    Set-Content $_.FullName $f                # save result back to input file
  }
```

Note:

- Consider adding `-noprofile` after `powershell`, so as to suppress potentially unnecessary loading of [profile files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles) - see the documentation of the Windows PowerShell CLI, [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe).
- Using `-ReadCount 0` with [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) greatly speeds up processing, because all lines are then read into a *single array*, instead of *streaming* the lines *one by one*, which requires *collecting* them in an array, which is much slower.
- Note: If a given file has *fewer* than 10 lines, the above solution won't work, because you can only assign to *existing* elements of an array (an array is a fixed-size data structure). If you need to deal wit this case, insert the following after the 
  `$f = $_ | Get-Content -ReadCount 0` line, which inserts empty lines as needed to ensure that at least 10 lines are present:

  ```bash
  if ($f.Count -lt 10) { $f += @('') * (10 - $f.Count) }
  ```

Answer (score -1):

Easiest solution I can think of is using the `-Index` parameter provided in `Select-Object` for that.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path .\Desktop\*.txt | % { Get-Content $_.FullName | Select-Object -Index 7,8 } |
    Out-File -FilePath .\Desktop\index.txt
```

**Edit**: based on your post.

Comment: The OP's code modifies existing lines and writes the modified file content as a whole back to the input file. By contrast, your solution extracts two lines (leaving aside that you're writing back to a _single_ file instead of to each input file).